# How to use ruby regexp to move xml tags in an xml document when they fall between ERB tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, regex, docx

I have a word docx with this in the document.xml file:

```
-<w:r><w:tab/>
  <w:t><%= @grantor
  </w:t></w:r>
-<w:r w:rsidR="008E7A5B">
  <w:t>1.upcase %>, MANAGER
</w:t></w:r>
```

I need to take the xml tags out from in between the ERB tags (<%= and %>) and place them behind the closing ERB bracket (%>).

Move this:

```
  </w:t></w:r>
-<w:r w:rsidR="008E7A5B">
  <w:t>
```

To end up with:

```
-<w:r><w:tab/>
  <w:t><%= @grantor1.upcase %>
  </w:t></w:r>
-<w:r w:rsidR="008E7A5B">
  <w:t>, MANAGER
</w:t></w:r>
```

I know it is not a good idea to use regex's for parsing XML, but this is trivial.  Probably need to loop through to each set of ERB tags, grab anything between the first "<" and the last ">" only between the ERB tags, not the rest of the document...and move them to be behind that %>.  This will work fine because I will never put "<" or ">" in my ERB tags for any reason.  All of this probably can't be done in a single regex, but I'm not sure how to go about it.  Maybe regex /<%=.+%>/ (not sure how to make this multiline), then loop through those instances and run regex on each.  But then I'm not sure how to do the moving.  As a newbie, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a word docx

That's your first problem.  Only deal with plain text files.

> but this is trivial

Not true--at all.

> I know it is not a good idea to use regex's for parsing XML

Your text is not valid XML anyway because it contains < and > characters in the content of a tag, for instance:

```
<w:t>
  <%= @grantor
</w:t>
```

So whether an xml parser can handle that broken xml is not certain.

Here's a much more robust solution:

```
str = %q{
<%= "hello" %>

<w:r>
  <w:tab/>
  <w:t><%= @grantor</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="008E7A5B">
  <w:t>1.upcase %>, MANAGER</w:t>
</w:r>

<%= "goodbye" %>

<w:r>
  <w:tab/>
  <w:t><%= @grantor</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="008E7A5B">
  <w:t>2.downcase %>, MANAGER</w:t>
</w:r>
}


str.gsub!(/<%= (.*?) %>/xms) do |match|
  erb_contents = Regexp.last_match[1]
  xml = ""

  if erb_contents.gsub!(/< .* >/xms, "")
    xml = Regexp.last_match[0]
  end

  "<%=#{erb_contents}%>#{xml}"
end

puts str

--output:--

<%= "hello" %>

<w:r>
  <w:tab/>
  <w:t><%= @grantor1.upcase %></w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="008E7A5B">
  <w:t>, MANAGER</w:t>
</w:r>

<%= "goodbye" %>

<w:r>
  <w:tab/>
  <w:t><%= @grantor2.downcase %></w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="008E7A5B">
  <w:t>, MANAGER</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, and I don't know anything about Reg Expressions.  You made good points, but they are irrelevant for what I'm trying to do.  1) I'm not working with a docx, just a .xml file.  2) It IS trivial. 3) It IS valid xml, I should've mentioned the erb tags <% %> show up &lt;% %&gt;.  They are typed in the word doc like text and Word forces the xml tags inside them sometimes.  I simply want to put any xml tags behind the erb for evaluation.